# Is it possible to animate multiple axis parameters as one spline?

Tags: animation, interpolation

I'm relatively new to animation and wonder if there is a way to animate multiple axes (position, rotation...) as a single animation curve. For example, I set two poses in frame 0 and frame 15, and I want to change the easing/interpolation between these poses by hand.

It would be perfect if there were a single curve to interpolate between these two poses, but as far as I know, people usually just tweak each curve separately. Or am I missing something?

Comment: A location is 3 values: xyz, so it's already 3 curves. You probably don't want the object to move along a single, straight line connecting points <0, 0, 0> and <1, 1, 1>. You could apply some multipliers to the relation between a coordinate and a single value driving it (e.g. a custom property suggested by A), but then it would still be a straight line, e.g. connecting <0, 0, 0> and <1, 2, 3> for <a, 2a, 3a> formula. Going further, you probably not only don't want location components to be synchronized like that, but also you don't actually want to synchronize rotation with location…

Comment: It seems you're asking for some kind of quality of life feature that will allow you e.g. set the interpolation mode for all keyframes of a given frame, but with a laconic question we can only guess what you actually want.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a custom property and make it drive as many properties as you want. If you keyframe the custom property, it will have a single animation curve. However, unless you're happy with a one-to-one relationship, you will still need to define how each of the driven properties will react to the custom property. This means that you will still probably need to customize a curve for each driven property, but it will be a one-time setup step.

Another option is to use an *Action* constraint. It takes one property as input and performs an action in response. Since an action can record the changes to as many properties as needed, this setup will create the one-to-many output you want. However, you still need to create that action which means manipulating a curve for each property the action has keyframes for.

[image: Action Constraint]